# Como fazer uma animação em CSS começando de um lado no Hover e terminando do outro quando sair o Hover?

Tags: css, css3, animação, css-hover, ui

Tenho uma animação onde um elemento aparece entrando da esquerda para direita quando faço o `:hover` no `.box`, porém gostaria de que quando eu tirasse o mouse do `.box` o elemento saísse agora pela direita.

A ideia é tipo assim, quando coloca o *mouse* no `box` o elemento entra pela esquerda e quando tira o mouse o elemento sai pela direita.
 *(Ou seja, no `hover` o elemento **entra e para no meio**, quanto sai do `hover` o elemento que entrou sai pelo outro lado)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E gostaria de algo como a imagem acima...

***O que eu consegui até o momento é o elemento entrando pela esquerda e tb saindo pela esquerda, mas eu quero que ele saia pelo outro lado!*** 
 **OBS:** eu deixei o `overflow: hidden` comentado no CSS para facilitar a visualização da animação, mas no final vou usar com o `overflow` ativado!

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    /* overflow: hidden; */ 
    
}
.filho {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    transition: left 500ms;
}
.box:hover .filho {
    left: 0%;
}
```

```html
Quando tirar o mouse o bloco vermelho deve sair pela direita...<br><br>
<div class="box">
    <div class="filho"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cheguei em duas soluções. Uma mais simples que seria ideal caso o elemento ocupe 100% da largura do `.box`. A outra é um pouco mais "sofisticada", e o elemento pode ter qualquer tamanho, porém precisa de um "ajuste" caso tenha conteúdo dentro do `.box`

**Opção 1**

A opção mais complicada e que é mais fiel a proposta da pergunta o que eu fiz foi "espelhar" o `.box` com `scaleX(-1)` quando se faz o `:hover` tão rápido que o olho não percebe e executa a animação entrando tipo de *traz para frente*, e quando vc tira o `:hover` do elemento ele retira esse `scaleX(-1)` e executa a animação saindo para o lado certo.

Pareceu confuso? Veja como fica o resultado:

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.filho {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
    transition: left 500ms;
}
.box:hover .filho {
    left: 0%;

}
.box:hover, 
.box:hover span {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <span>texto</span>
    <div class="filho"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Opção 2**

Agora uma opção u pouco mas simples, onde eu usei `transform: scaleX(0);` para "esconder" o elemento a esquerda e usei e `transform-origin: right;` para fazer ele "crescer" para a direita. E no `:hover` eu fiz o inverso `transform-origin: left;` para fazer ele desaparecer saindo pela esquerda (*left*).

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.filho {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: transform 500ms;
}
.box:hover .filho{
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <span>texto</span>
    <div class="filho"></div>
</div>
```